# Update Every Azure Table Storage Partition Key and Row Key

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I've just added 20,000,000 rows to Azure table storage.

Unfortunately, I didn't trim the partition key or row key so my keys are:

'xxx ' & 'yyy ' instead of 'xxx' & 'yyy'

Can this be corrected?

Comment: There is no update to table storage partition and row key. You'll need to delete and add again.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected that.